# How does adding a second pod instance in a single node cluster help to scale up?

Tags: kubernetes

In K8s we can have a single-node cluster. This node can deploy one instance of our application and if users are increasing from what I have read more instances are launched in the same node and as more and more users are added up more nodes are added to the cluster to allow scale.
My question is specifically about the singly node. If we have e.g. a web application deployed as an image in a pod and more users are added up, how is it useful to scale up to deploy another pod in the same node?
It seems to me it won't offer any benefit because any limits the first instance of the web application would encounter would only by the host machine itself. Hence adding a second pod how would it help?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming.

Comment: @Turing85: Aren't questions about scalability and architecture relevant here? If not which stackexchange is more suitable?

Comment: As I said: questions asked here must be related to programming, which your question is not; it is about infrastructure. I am not certain it is on-topic for any SE site. You may try [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [sf] after checking if the question is on-topic there. I would, however, recommend to study the documentation of both docker and kubernetes beforehand.

Comment: This question has really nothing to do with kubernetes. Would it be (**in your particular case**) any difference if you start multiple instances of your application vs one instance on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

In kubernetes there are concepts like [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/), [Inter pod affinity and anti affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity).

The resource values defined in the manifests, like requests and limits pay a key role for HPA to work.

For ex: if there is limit value defined as 0.5vCPU at pod level and there is an HPA definition which has 75% usage of CPU, based on this metric a new pod will be scheduled when the first pod cross 75% of its capacity.  So now the application will have two pods of 0.5vCPU each equivalent to 1vCPU.

For your first question - based on above example it will have more resources to serve more requests as the capacity is increased.

For your second question - before scheduling the new pod onto the node it will calculate the availability of resources and if its only available then only pod will be scheduled onto the node.  Also if you want to deploy strategy not schedule the pod on the same node if the one pod is already running then you can use pod anti affinity rules.

More details of HPA and pod affinity rules are explained k8s documentation shared in above links.